# React-select value set to null on first selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, react-select

I'm building a dropdown using `react-select` : https://react-select.com/home

My options for the dropdown are coming from a API call to a list. The issue I'm having is when you first select an option my `AccountSelected1` says it's still `null` when I select another option than it starts to store in my `AccountSelected1` state. However what it ends up storing is the previous selected option.

```
AccountSelected1: any,

AccountSelected1: null,

handleChangeAccountSelected1 = AccountSelected1 => {
    console.log(AccountSelected1);
    this.setState({ AccountSelected1: AccountSelected1.value}); 
    console.log(`AccountSelected1 set to:`, this.state.AccountSelected1); 
};  

public render(): React.ReactElement<WebappProps> {

    const { AccountSelected1 } =this.state;
        <Select
            value={AccountSelected1}
            onChange={this.handleChangeAccountSelected1} 
            options={this.state.AccountList}
        />
    return (

    )
}
```

Here is my console. As you can see it begins to store the second time with the previous `value`

```
//Console for First selection
{value: "23422", label: "23422", Description: "Account for Jeff"}
GLAccountSelected set to: null

//Console for Second selection
{value: "68755", label: "68755", Description: "Account for Lou"}
GLAccountSelected set to: 23422
```

Comment: ```this.setState``` is ```asynchronous```, if you want to see the real value you need to use it this way: ```this.setState({ AccountSelected1: AccountSelected1.value }, () => { console.log(this.state.AccountSelected1); });```

Comment: @CevaComic let me try this out. Right below that field I'm displaying the `Description` of the selected option. With the answer you provided now the `Description` is null. Here is what I had `Selected: {this.state.AccountSelected1.Description}`

Comment: That's because you're not updateing the state with the hole object, you're just sending it's value :). the callback i showed you, it only gets the new assigned value in the state and logs it. Nothing more.

Comment: @CevaComic I see. I'm new to react. But I understand what you're saying. So if I needed it to update the Description to the new assigned value how should I approach that? If you can put that as an answer instead of a comment. I can set it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you don't get the description. I think you should set the whole object into state, your `handleChangeAccountSelected1` should look like this:

```
handleChangeAccountSelected1 = AccountSelected1 => {
    console.log('AccountSelected1 BEFORE',this.state.AccountSelected1);
    this.setState({ AccountSelected1 },() => {
        console.log('AccountSelected1 AFTER',this.state.AccountSelected1);
    }); 
};
```